# Creating a resteasy client with google-app-engine throws a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, resteasy

I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor when using Resteasy with google-app-engine while creating a resteasy client.

```
      import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest;
      import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse;

      public class Demo{
         public void testConnection()
         {
            ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("url");
            request.accept("application/json");

            request.body("application/json", body);

            response = request.put(String.class);
         }
      }
```

Exception is raised while intilaizing the ClientRequest class. Error strack trace is as follows:

```
{java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:127)    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:148)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.getDefaultExecutor(ClientRequest.java:87)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.<init>(ClientRequest.java:97)}
```

Comment: You should use a more appropriate title to describe your problem and its context for future reference by other users

Comment: Have you checked the resteasy jar dependencies? Have you included all the appropriate dependencies in your classpath?

Comment: Yes i have included all the dependencies. Httpclient is not supported by appengine in resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar. It is working with resteasy-jaxrs-2.0.1.GA.jar but only in localhost not in server.